how to import svg to Button in QML of QT5.12.12
I have imported this svg on button.
However, it doesn't display exactly.
Only background color is imported.
How to build same button including Gradient, radius, shadow, stroke and so on?
Button {
     id: inputRisk
     width: 110
     height: 110
     background: Rectangle {
        id: inputRiskbackgroung
        implicitWidth: 110
        implicitHeight: 110
        anchors.fill: parent
        Image {
            id: inputRiskImage
            source: "qrc/Main (1).svg"
            anchors.fill: parent
        }
    }
}

This is my current code.
I updated QML code but I cant see the change of result

At first glance your problem bases on your resource file and the way you try to link to its contents. Without more inside to your project, it is hard to tell where the problem starts. I recomment reading this resource: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/resources.html

There is no need for Rectangle here since you don't use its  specified properties like border or background color. And even more so, it's not worth using implicit size and anchors.*  together. Image probably has no size, you have to use some anchors properties. That besides some resource issues.

Even though knowing almost nothing about QML, "qrc/Main (1).svg" is just wrong. Please read the Qt resources docs linked above more carefully.

Qt SVG implements static features of SVG 1.2 Tiny.
If your SVG uses features beyond this specification you may attempt to replace them with equivalent SVG 1.2 Tiny elements.
If this still doesn't achieve your rendering requirements you can seek alternative QML components such as Rectangle, Shape, ShapePath, ConicalGradient, PathArc QML components.
    Button {
        id: btn
        width: 110
        height: 110
        background: Rectangle {
            radius: 30
            color: palette.button
            Shape {
                width: 110
                height: 110
                ShapePath {
                    strokeWidth: 0
                    strokeColor: "transparent"
                    fillGradient: ConicalGradient {
                        angle: 0
                        centerX: 55
                        centerY: 55
                        GradientStop { position: 0; color: ("green") }
                        GradientStop { position: 0.1; color: ("yellow") }
                        GradientStop { position: 0.3; color: ("orange") }
                        GradientStop { position: 0.5; color: ("red") }
                    }
                    startX: 5
                    startY: 55
                    PathArc {
                        x: 105; y: 55
                        radiusX: 50; radiusY: 50
                    }
                }
            }
            Label {
                anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                anchors.bottomMargin: 20
                text: "Risk"
            }
            Rectangle {
                anchors.fill: parent
                radius: 30
                color: "black"
                opacity: btn.pressed ? 0.2 : 0
            }
        }
    }

You can Try it Online!
References:

https://www.w3.org/TR/SVGTiny12/
https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/svgrendering.html.
https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-rectangle.html#radius-prop
https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-gradient.html
https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-shapes-shape.html
https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-shapes-shapepath.html
https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-shapes-conicalgradient.html
https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-gradientstop.html
https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-patharc.html
https://www.qt.io/blog/qt-svg-not-so-1.2-tiny-any-more

